# Iphone code and android

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c, dictionary

```
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [[self item] setObject:self.currentDay forKey:@"day"];
```

This is the code for iphone wat is its equivalent in java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
item.put( "day", currentDay );
```

Comment: wow.. tanks for the answer. its very helpful for someone new to android like me ... tanks.

Comment: @suslovjb: This is Java, actually, nothing specific to Android here :)

Comment: sorry for accepting it late... ass soon as i got the answer i clicked the tick mark but accept can be done only after 8 minutes... @kovpas ya i know.. i am new to java as well..